# check if a php file is running on background

Tags: php, linux, ssh

I have a cronjob that is running every hour and there is a loop in it that loop every seconds.

This is a sample of the cron file which is named processor.php

```
$i=1
while($i<3600){
sleep(1);
$i++;
}
```

I found out my webserver was down for half hour last night. Now I am going to make a program on different server, if see my server is not alive. connect thru ssh to server then restarts httpd and mysqld.

But I am worry about the cronjobes so I want to know if there is a command to show after restarting processor.php is running or not. if not , try to run.

Now my question is how can I see a processor.php is working on background or not. I see this in htop but I need something like ps command.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not ping the server and check the response code

Comment: I want to exactly do it, but I want to sure if my server services is restarted then my processor files will run after restarting!

Comment: `ps -A u` and `ps aux` show which processes are running. Try to look at the result e.g. grep for the php-file and the services

Answer (score 2):

Do a bash script like this, and add it to your cron.

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -ef|grep phpscript.php |grep -v grep
if [ $? = "0" ]
then
  echo "Running"
else
  echo "Restart"
  /path/to/restart/phpscript.php
fi
```